# How to define hourly interval in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file showing daily sales in months. Problem is, I want to calculate the sales made in a given time interval. Sample of my first nine (9):

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': ['2020-02-01 00:13:00', '2020-02-01 02:10:00', '2020-02-01 03:03:00', 
                                '2020-02-01 06:52:00', '2020-02-01 09:19:00', '2020-02-01 09:50:00',
                                '2020-02-01 10:00:00', '2020-02-01 10:06:00', '2020-02-19 21:43:00'],
                       'Amount': [2000, 26080, 5060, 800, 3000, 10934, 2250, 3600, 11528] })
```

All I want to do is get the sum of sales made in the following time periods:
'00:00:00' - '04:59:00'
'05:00:00' - '07:59:00'
'08:00:00' - '10:00:00'
'11:00:00' - '23:59:00'

I tried using Pandas `dataframe.between_time()` but then the results are no desirable.

```
a = sales.between_time('00:00:00', '04:59:00')['Amount'].sum
b = sales.between_time('05:00:00', '07:59:00')['Amount'].sum
c = sales.between_time('08:00:00', '10:00:00')['Amount'].sum
d = sales.between_time('11:00:00', '23:59:00')['Amount'].sum
```

Is there a Pythonic way of summing the sales made in a given time intervals of my problem?

Comment: Why are the results "not desirable" ? And didn't you forget the parenthesis for the `.sum()` ?

Comment: You are right. Actually my Amount column was string. I changed it to numeric and then added the `()` at the end and then it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty much there, just change the Date column to a timestamp rather than a string, set it as the index and you're good to go

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': ['2020-02-01 00:13:00', '2020-02-01 02:10:00', '2020-02-01 03:03:00', 
    '2020-02-01 06:52:00', '2020-02-01 09:19:00', '2020-02-01 09:50:00',
    '2020-02-01 10:00:00', '2020-02-01 10:06:00', '2020-02-19 21:43:00'],
    'Amount': [2000, 26080, 5060, 800, 3000, 10934, 2250, 3600, 11528] })

sales['Date'] = sales['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x), 1) 
sales = sales.set_index('Date')
```

Now we can use between_time

```
a = sales.between_time('00:00:00', '04:59:00')['Amount'].sum()
print(a) <- 33140
```

There are more efficient ways to get a timestamp but the above should work

Comment: As a useful aside: Try and use Pandas resample https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html to have the data in a useful "hourly" shape. `sales.resample('60min', offset='00h00min').sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the corresponding value to amount at `'04:59:00'` so it is is not possible to do so. If there is data available at these intervals then it would be possible

Comment: In the given first 9, Yes. But I have that time somewhere in the dataframe. I could exclude the end with `include_end = False` but all I want to do is just to find the sum of sales occurring between 00:00 AM  to 4:59AM

Comment: Please tell if the issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

I make a column of Time only. Check this:

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': ['2020-02-01 00:13:00', '2020-02-01 02:10:00', '2020-02-01 03:03:00', 
                                '2020-02-01 06:52:00', '2020-02-01 09:19:00', '2020-02-01 09:50:00',
                                '2020-02-01 10:00:00', '2020-02-01 10:06:00', '2020-02-19 21:43:00'],
                       'Amount': [2000, 26080, 5060, 800, 3000, 10934, 2250, 3600, 11528] })

sales["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(sales["Date"]).dt.time
a = sales[(sales["Time"] > pd.to_datetime("00:00:00").time()) & (sales["Time"] < pd.to_datetime("04:59:00").time())]["Amount"].sum()
print(a)

>>> 33140
```